# Error when installing matplotlib module python in Blender

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to install matplotlib module of python in Blender. But it fails with the following error. Anyone knows why? Thanks.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\python\bin\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o1202pv5\\matplotlib_d6df7f3de6254447bb0d9925c891b5c1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tongf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o1202pv5\\matplotlib_d6df7f3de6254447bb0d9925c891b5c1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\tongf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y9zlg1kw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\python\Include\matplotlib'
     cwd: C:\Users\tongf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o1202pv5\matplotlib_d6df7f3de6254447bb0d9925c891b5c1\
Complete output (549 lines):

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
  matplotlib: yes [3.4.3]
      python: yes [3.9.2 (default, Mar  1 2021, 08:18:55) [MSC v.1916 64 bit
                  (AMD64)]]
    platform: yes [win32]
       tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

running install
running build
running build_py
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
copying lib\pylab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib
copying lib\matplotlib\afm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib
```

...`enter code here`